# How can I reset and prepoulate all users in django?

Tags: django, reset, django-users

I'm developing a django application with some complicated user interactions, so I need to do a lot of testing. Is there an easy way to clear out the Users table (and all associated tables) in the database to start fresh? Also, is there a good way to autopopulate the database with "test users" to play around with?

Details:

- This is an operation I expect to carry out several times, so it'd be nice to be able to run it quickly from the command line.
- I'm using the basic Users model (django.contrib.auth.models.User) in django 1.3.1
- I'm *not* using the admin pages, and would rather keep it that way, unless things get really desparate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for auto-populating, have a look at [django fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)

loading fixtures will overwrite changes, but not delete any additions. to clear the table, you want

```
User.objects.all().delete()
```

This will also propage to anything with foreign keys referring to users. To do this from the command line, wrap this in a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Comment: Related question -- is there any way to reset the keys in the User index table so that the index of the next User created will be pk=1?  It seems that User.objects.all.delete() deletes table entries, but doesn't reset the inedx.

Comment: hm. not sure. i guess you could always drop the table and run `syncdb` again. (`syncdb` leaves any existing tables alone)